# show keyboard indicator in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, keyboard

I have been trying to show the keyboard indicator in ubuntu 13.04. It is only available at the log in window at the right top of the panel, but ones getting in my account the menu strangely disappears.

Comment: Do you have more that one layout?

Answer (score 1):

The indicator will not show if only one layout is available.  Once you add another keyboard layout, the indicator will show.  See images below.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two keyboard settings in System Settings

## Keyboard Layout

This is where you change keyboard layouts

## Keyboars

Offers speed, delay and cursor settings.

I believe you are looking for **Keyboard Layout**

Hope this helps